# using java to convert multiple color images to grayscale and saving them in files

Tags: java

I have created two separate java classes. One to convert color images to grayscale and another to save images in files. This is the code I wrote for the classes:

**GrayScaleConverter**

```
import java.io.*;

public class GrayScaleConverter {
    //I started with the image I wanted (inImage)
    public ImageResource makeGray(ImageResource inImage) {
        //I made a blank image of the same size
        ImageResource outImage = new ImageResource(inImage.getWidth(), inImage.getHeight());
        //for each pixel in outImage
        for (Pixel pixel: outImage.pixels()) {
            //look at the corresponding pixel in inImage
            Pixel inPixel = inImage.getPixel(pixel.getX(), pixel.getY());
            //compute inPixel's red + inPixel's blue + inPixel's green
            //divide that sum by 3 (call it average)
            int average = (inPixel.getRed() + inPixel.getBlue() + inPixel.getGreen())/3;
            //set pixel's red to average
            pixel.setRed(average);
            //set pixel's green to average
            pixel.setGreen(average);
            //set pixel's blue to average
            pixel.setBlue(average);
        }
        //outImage is your answer
        return outImage;
    }

    public void selectAndConvert () {
        DirectoryResource dr = new DirectoryResource();
        for (File f : dr.selectedFiles()) {
            ImageResource inImage = new ImageResource(f);
            ImageResource gray = makeGray(inImage);
            gray.draw();
        }
    }

    public void testGray() {
        ImageResource ir = new ImageResource();
        ImageResource gray = makeGray(ir);
        gray.draw();
    }
}
```

**ImageSaver**

```
import java.io.File;

public class ImageSaver {
    public void doSave() {
        DirectoryResource dr = new DirectoryResource();
        for(File f : dr.selectedFiles() ){
            ImageResource image = new ImageResource(f);
            String fname = image.getFileName();
            String newName = "copy -" + fname;
            image.setFileName(newName);
            image.draw();
            image.save();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to combine the code from these two classes such that I will be able to select multiple color images, convert them to gray scale and save the new grayscale copies in separate files simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `DirectoryResource` and `ImageResource`
but the answer could be something like this:

modify class `GrayScaleConverter` method `selectAndConvert ()` as following:

```
public void selectAndConvert () {
    DirectoryResource dr = new DirectoryResource();
    ImageSaver imageSaver = new ImageSaver ();

    for (File f : dr.selectedFiles()) {
        ImageResource inImage = new ImageResource(f);
        ImageResource gray = makeGray(inImage);
        gray.draw();
        gray.setFileName(inImage.getFileName());
        imageSaver.doSave(gray);
    }
}
```

modify `ImageSaver` class so that method `doSave()` takes parameter `ImageResource` and save it
and remove the for loop, work with 1 image at a time:

```
public void doSave(ImageResource image) {
    String newName = "copy -" + image.getFileName();//shortcut, no need for 2 string variables
    image.setFileName(newName);
    // not sure if a draw() needed again, as it was called in selectAndConvert() but i am not familiar with those Resource classes.
    image.draw(); 
    image.save();
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what you did in this section of code, Imagesaver ImageSaver = new ImageSaver(); ? I have never seen this done before and it looks like you created an object and gave it a name identical to the class ImageSaver. Also can the same result be achieved using inheritance. For instance, public class GrayScaleConverter extends ImageSaver { and then calling the doSave() method. I tried using gray.doSave() and i got an error message saying cannot find symbol.

Comment: @J.Mars yes i have created an object but the name is not identical notice 1st character in object name is lower-case (small letter) and you know Java is case sensitive, and this is a good practice to keep following on which object is which type, If `GrayScaleConverter` extends `ImageSaver`, then remove this line and call `doSave()` directly.